# why can't i use casting to deal with pointer to pointer variable without using double asterisks? - This is purely academic

Tags: c, pointers, casting, segmentation-fault, pointer-to-pointer

I was just trying something to understand pointer to pointer deeply. I write the code below

```
int x = 20;
int *p0 = &x;
int *p1 = &p0;
printf("*p0 = %d\n", *p0);
printf("**p1 = %d\n", *((int *)*p1));
```

I thought the output would be

```
*p0 = 20
**p1 = 20
```

As *p1 would be evaluated to the address of x as an integer value and then I could use casting to de-reference the value in address x. since the value of *p1 represents a valid memory location of x. But the output was

[image: snapshot from xterm for output of the code]

I would like to understand this behavior.

**NOTE - this is purely academic, I have no intention to write code this way**

Comment: Is this C++ or C?

Comment: `int *p1 = &p0;` should be `int **p1 = &p0;` Please check out compiler warnings.

Comment: @WeatherVane his question was why it cause seg fault not how he should write the code

Comment: This is in C programming language

Comment: @ 
Weather Vane
I know this is the right way to write it but I ask to understand why this is not possible to understand how dereferenc operator work

Comment: @AsafItach if the code does not compile - live - https://godbolt.org/z/6n1EPMv7x - how did it produce a segfault. WeatherVane's comment was to the point.

Comment: @RichardCritten It generates 2 warning but it compiles and return 139 (segfault)

Comment: Even if you `reinterpret_cast` here, it's likely that pointers are 64 bit and `int`s 32 bit on your system meaning you loose half of the info of the pointer because `int` is an intermediate type used.

Comment: Because `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int*)` and you loose the address: `warning: initialization of ‘int *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int **’ `

Comment: (1) If your program compiles with warnings, don't bother running it. Fix the warnings first. (2) A cast is an instruction to the compiler to shut up. Don't use casts unless you know your types better than the compiler does.

Comment: @MohammedAmer the segfault was a result of writing faulty code. If your car is squashed by a truck when you run a red light, it does not make much sense to examine what part of the truck caused damage. The solution is not to run the red light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to know is why this is happening:

let's say there are 3 boxes of memory

x      y      z
20    &x      &y

why cant you do that *((int *) *z) => => *y => => x

and the answer is you should **compile your code with warning flags** and not write code like this!!

But, you can make it work by casting it as you want to treat it.

instead of

```
printf("**p1 = %d\n", *((int *)*p1));
```

you should write:

```
printf("**p1 = %d\n", *((int *)*((int **)p1)));
```

z is declared as int * so when you do this *z - the compiler **knows** it's an int not an int* so you can't take a 1-byte variable and treat it like it is a 4-byte variable

and for those who think it cant be compiled:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This line is not valid C or C++:

```
int *p1 = &p0;
```

The fact that you say you have compiled and run this code means that you have not turned on error checking in your compiler.  You really must do that, otherwise you will write all kinds of code with undefined behavior which can crash or worse.

If you use GCC or Clang, run it with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.  Then it will not compile your erroneous code.

Comment: It gives me two warning 
[-wincompatible-pointer-types]
[-wint-to-pointer-cast]